# How to use instance variable in where section of Spock Test

Tags: spock

Spock only allows static variables to be accessed from where block.

Is there any workaround using which Instance variables can be used inside the where block ?

Comment: do you have a code sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: There is no workaround that allows to use instance variables in a where-block. There may be a way to solve your bigger goal, but you'd have to explain it.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - I was trying to declare an abstract getter of a field so that the derived class has to declare the variable, I want to access the fields of this variable in the where block . If I declare the variable in the derived class it doesnt work, however I found a workaround , I have not declared the variable in derived class but the getter and returned anonymous object .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can annotate instance variables with `@Shared`, see Spock manual, chapter ["Sharing of Objects between Iterations"](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_sharing_of_objects_between_iterations).

**Attention:** Shared instance variables will retain their values in between iterations and be shared between methods. If you do not want this, do not use the approach. But as I understand you, you initialise variable values using tables or so in the `where` block anyway, so it should be okay.